# LineChart problem

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I have an array of objects looking like this

> obj.date=23/02/2010, obj.regType=0,
>   obj.value=1000;
>
> obj.date=23/03/2010, obj.regType=0,
>   obj.value=500;
>
> obj.date=23/02/2010, obj.regType=1,
>   obj.value=500;
>
> obj.date=23/04/2010, obj.regType=1,
>   obj.value=1000;

I want the line series to be by regType. On the x-axis to have the dates and on the y-axis to have the values.

Is it possible to do that? because i looked on the internet and the examples did not help me.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do what you're asking. Use the Draw API.

Comment: No need for Drawing API. If you can arrange those objects into two separate collections by `regType` most of the work is done. Then create two LineSeries with xField set to `date` and yField to `value` and bind one collection for each as a `dataProvider`. I created this minimal example for earlier post: http://pastebin.com/5EJC21wT (dataCanvas part isn't related to this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might as well add this as an answer:

No need for Drawing API. If you can arrange those objects into two separate collections by `regType` most of the work is done. Then create two LineSeries with xField set to `date` and yField to `value` and bind one collection for each as a `dataProvider`.

New minimal example where collection manipulation is handled quite nicely with ListCollectionView:

- http://pastebin.com/jkyn2UEz